# How can I use if statements to check variables inside of function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a text based hacking game. How can I use if statements to check variables inside of  function?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python Projects\TextHackingGame\Start.py", line 22, in <module>
    if check == "start":
NameError: name 'check' is not defined
```

The code:

```
import time
import string
import os
import sys

print("-------------------------")
print("Welcome to [NAME_HERE]")
print("By ***************")
print("Copyright 2018")
print("-------------------------")
time.sleep(0.10)
os.system("cls")

global Check
global check

def StartOrChange():
    print("Type 'Start' or 'Changelog'.")
    Check = input("> ")
    check = Check.lower

if check == "start":
    pass
elif check == "changelog":
    pass
else:
    print("Please enter 'Start' or 'Changelog'")
```

Comment: `global <name>` goes inside a function that tries to alter the global.

Comment: Make sure you indentation is the same here as in your file. If it's the same, that's where your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your variables, use `check = 0` and `Check = 0`, and inside the function `StartOrChange()` use

```
def StartOrChange():
     global Check
     global check

     print("Type 'Start' or 'Changelog'.")
     Check = input("> ")
     print (Check) 
     check = Check.lower()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html